# React Native Expo оптимизация кода, ошибка отрисовки списка?

Tags: react-native, expo

Всем привет, имеется следующий код:

```
import React, { PureComponent } from "react";
import { View, Text, FlatList } from "react-native";

class ListItem extends PureComponent {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Проверка освобождения памяти из ОЗУ</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends PureComponent {
  renderItem = ({ item }) => {
    return <ListItem />;
  };

  keyExtractor = (_, item_index) => `test-${item_index}`;

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <FlatList
          removeClippedSubviews={true} // Освобождение элементов, находящихся вне видимой области
          initialNumToRender={10}
          maxToRenderPerBatch={10}
          windowSize={10}
          data={Array.from({ length: 400 })}
          keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}
          renderItem={this.renderItem}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default HomeScreen;
```

Почему при прокрутке страницы, я сталкиваюсь с ошибкой:

```
VirtualizedList: You have a large list that is slow to update - make sure your renderItem function renders components that follow React performance best practices like PureComponent, shouldComponentUpdate, etc. Object {
  "contentLength": 5320,
  "dt": 790,
  "prevDt": 2258,
}
```

Как мне оптимизировать код?